# How to find interface implementations with `gopls` and `lsp-mode`?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, golang

While running `gopls` and `lsp-mode` on a Golang project, is there a way to list all implementations of an interface's function?

When invoked on a function name, `xref-find-definition` jumps inside the interface definition. For example, M-. on function `area` in this [example](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) will jump to the area() line in:

```
type geometry interface {
    area() float64
    perim() float64
}
```

..and not to its implementation. This is expected behavior since only at runtime could the actual function that gets called be derived.

As for `xref-find-references`, the list does not include the function definitions - just the interface definition and calls to it, which again, makes sense.

However, this is not what one often looks for when they want to jump based on a function call. Is there a way to jump to or list *implementations* of an interface's function?

Answer (score 0):

`lsp-find-implementation` is the function that does exactly that. The `xref` interface doesn't include a function for searching for interface implementations, so it's provided by `lsp-mode` independently of `xref`.